# How can I tell when documents have been indexed?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, indexing, latency

Somewhat following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65971785/595305) which I asked yesterday, which shows that Elasticsearch-as-a-service in W10 takes a certain finite time to allow requests after the service has been started, even several seconds after an `Elasticsearch` object has actually been delivered in the Python script, I now find that if I add documents to an index and immediately query the index I get no results (but if I wait a few seconds I do get the expected results).

I am reading a book on ES as I learn, and there was something there about index updates happening only once a second (the book covers ES 1.7, I'm using 7.10).

The question is, after adding documents, is there some command I can run (Python `elasticsearch` module or possibly a REST URL...) which will either not return until the new documents have been indexed, or indicate somehow how many documents are now in the index, after having been indexed?

NB I am using this sort of command to index:

```
es_obj.index( index='my_index', body=record_as_json_string )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**

Yes, you can use the refresh API in multiple ways to achieve it.

For instance, below will insert and refresh immediately.

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/test/_doc/1?refresh&pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{"test": "test"}
'
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/test/_doc/2?refresh=true&pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{"test": "test"}
'
```

From the documentation:

> Refresh the relevant primary and replica shards (not the whole index) immediately after the operation occurs, so that the updated document appears in search results immediately. This should ONLY be done after careful thought and verification that it does not lead to poor performance, both from an indexing and a search standpoint.

Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-refresh.html

**Should you do it?**

The default settings are kept that way to give better performance. Since ES is mostly used to store large data sets, and refresh is a costlier operation, refreshing after every insert might lead you into unforeseen delays and performance issues.
The above mentioned [source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-refresh.html) highlights when to use what. Refer [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-indexing-speed.html#_unset_or_increase_the_refresh_interval) for better explanation on performance tuning.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I certainly won't be doing it after every `index` op. I already find that indexing 40,000 records with that command takes ages (compared with using a Lucene index directly in Java, which I've done previously), and am looking into the bulk indexing thing.